# Porque as requisições XHR do Facebook tem esse código?

Tags: javascript, facebook, loop

Eu estava analisando as requisições XHR do Facebook para fins de estudo e me deparei com um código que achei no mínimo curioso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No link parecido com esse **4-edge-chat.facebook.com/pull**, tem o seguinte código:

```
for (;;); {"t":"fullReload","seq":3}
```

Pois bem! Até onde eu sei, esse `for(;;)` causa um loop infinito (que até mesmo pode travar o navegador se executar ele no `console`).

Qual será o motivo de alguns dos scripts do Facebook ter esse código? Seria para evitar inclusão externa ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Só para deixar vinculado aqui a mesma pergunta no SOen; http://stackoverflow.com/q/2669690/91403 (pois pode servir de complemento a resposta já aceita)

Comment: Muito útil, @renatoargh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR

Sim, é para evitar um tipo muito específico de ataque baseado em requisições Json em domínios diferentes.

## Um tipo de ataque

Segundo [um artigo do You've Been Haacked](http://haacked.com/), um dos ataques desta categoria podem ser classificado como uma combinação entre [*cross-site request forgery* ou **XSRF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) e algumas brechas em navegadores antigos que permitiam a scripts maliciosos ler todo ou parte do conteúdo retornado de requisições JSON para outros domínimos.

XSRF resumidamente é quando um script malicioso faz requisições para um servidor remoto (Facebook, neste caso) usando as credenciais do usuário para atuar em nome do usuário ou obter dados confidenciais.

## Como o ataque funciona

A ideia é basicamente a a seguinte:

1. O usuário autentica-se no Facebook
2. O usuário acessa um site malicioso
3. Um script no site malicioso usa uma tag `<script>` para fazer uma requisição `GET` ao web service do Facebook que retorna um JSON
4. O script malicioso consegue burlar a segurança do navegador e obter os dados retornados da requisição ao Facebook

## Exemplo de implementação do ataque

Extraído do site citado acima, considere o exemplo a seguir:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var secrets;

Array = function() {
  secrets = this;
};


<script src="http://haacked.com/demos/secret-info.json" 
  type="text/javascript">

<script type="text/javascript">

  var yourData = '';
  var i = -1;
  while(secrets[++i]) {
    yourData += secrets[i] + ' ';
  }

  alert('I stole your data: ' + yourData);
</script>
```

Em alguns navegadores mais antigos, o código acima faz com que a variável `secrets` receba os valores de qualquer novo `Array` criado após a execução do trecho inicial. É uma redeclaração do construtor.

Em seguida, a tag `<script>` faz a requisição ao outro servidor e, se houver um `Array` no JSON retornado, os dados serão capturados.

## Conclusão

Mesmo que os navegadores modernos dificultem bastante a captura de dados em tais tipos de requisição, o loop infinito `for` faz com que o script malicioso não tenha chance alguma de fazer algo com possíveis dados que poderiam ser obtidos em chamadas a web services usando tags `<script>`.

Portanto, é um elemento a mais na segurança.

Comment: Muito bem explicado! Muito obrigado pela dedicação

Comment: O pessoal do facebook foi muito inteligente nessa implementação. O curioso é pensar em como eles devem tratar esse código para ele ser válido internamente :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Para funcionar só precisa o trabalho manual de fazer *substring* sempre que for fazer o *parse* desses dados.

Comment: rsrsrsrs, eu tinha acabado de mostrar uma solução assim para um colega meu. Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Seria então uma boa prática inserir no inicio de cada JSON retornado o loop infinito? É que tenho uma aplicação feita em angular que faz requisições ao servidor que por sua vez retorna a resposta em JSON. Do lado do servidor verifico se o cliente está logado, mas se o utilizador estiver infectado com algum código malicioso, requisições podem ser feitas automaticamente em "nome" do utilizador logado. Certo?